# Show this a tempered distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, dual-spaces

I want to show that $f(x) : = e^{ie^x}$ is a tempered distribution. Therefore I need to show that for all $\varphi \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$, that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) e^{ie^x}dx < \infty.$$ Equivalently, I could show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \mathcal{F}(e^{ie^x})dx < \infty,$$ where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform. I have had no luck with this as of yet.

Comment: Can you show that $\varphi \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})\implies \varphi \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then it is true

Comment: It is much easier. Since $|f(x)|\le 1$, it is a bounded function and so a tempered distribution.

Answer (score 4):

As *Guy Fsone* pointed out, it es enough to know that Schwartz-functions are integrable to prove that the integral against $e^{ie^x}$ is finite. The simple reason for that is just that $\vert e^{ie^x} \vert =1$ for all $x$.

On the other hand you need a little more. By showing that the integral is finite, you prove that integration against $e^{ie^x}$ is a well defined linear map $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. To prove that it is a tempered distribution it remains to show the continuity of that map.

Equivalently you can prove a bound of the form
$$\left\vert \int \varphi(x) e^{ie^x} dx \right\vert \le C p_N(\varphi)$$
where $p_N(\phi) = \max_{k,l\le N} \vert\vert x^k \phi^{(l)} \vert\vert_{L^\infty}$ is one of the seminorms of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

In order to get this bound observe that
$$ \left\vert \int \varphi(x) e^{ie^x} dx \right\vert \le \int \vert(1+x^2)\varphi(x)\vert \cdot (1+x^2)^{-1} dx \le \int (1+x^2)^{-1} dx  \cdot \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert(1+x^2)\varphi(x)\vert $$
Now it is not to hard to see that the first factor is some finite number $C/2$ and the second factor is $\le 2 p_2(\varphi)$. This proves the statement. (The argument of course also works if you replace $f$ by any other bounded function.)

Comment: Why is the second factor less than $\le 2 p_2(\varphi)$? Wouldn't the $+1$ be an issue or does the times 2 take care of the $+1$?

Comment: Exactly, $\sup \vert (1+x^2)\varphi(x) \vert \le \sup \vert \varphi(x) \vert + \sup \vert x^2\varphi(x) \vert \le p_2(\varphi) + p_2(\varphi)$.

Comment: Furthermore, I guess would it be more accurate to bound the integral with $C\sum_{k,l \leq N}^n p_{k,l}(\varphi)$? Since $p_N(\varphi) = \max_{k,l\le N} \vert\vert x^k \varphi^{(l)} \vert\vert_{L^\infty}$ is not the norm of the tempered distributions but rather the Schwarz functions?

Comment: The bound in my answer is fine. Obviously $p_2(\varphi)$ is bounded by a sum as you wrote it. Further, I am using the following result: *If $X$ is an [LCTVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space) with seminorms $p_1\le p_2 \le \dots$, then a linear functional $T\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous iff $\vert Tx \vert \lesssim p_N(x)$ for some $N$.* Here $X=\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, so I need the semi norms of the Schwartz space.